# Intellij + Gradle: properties file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

My configuration:

Gradle installed via Homebrew (Mac OS), Intellij Idea 13.

Preferences:

"Use default Gradle wrapper"
and gradle home: `/Users/my_username/.gradle`

---

For the following project:

```
/
 build.gradle
 gradle.properties
```

The gradle.properties file contains a variable `NAME = PJ`.
I also have a gradle.properties under `/Users/my_username/.gradle/gradle.properties` having a variable `TEST=Hello`.

For the given task, gradle prints Hello and null

```
task hello << {
    println TEST
    println NAME
}
```

Which means that it does not read by default the gradle.properties in the same directory. Is it a normal behavior or do I miss something in path variable so can the build.gradle script can read it?

A work-around I found is to add:

```
file("gradle.properties").withInputStream {
    stream -> new Properties().load(stream)
}
```

When I used android studio the .properties file of the same dir was automatically imported.

PS: Although TEST var gets printed I get a warning for `Cannot resolve symbol`. I saw around and this is typical error (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With gradle `2.0` it works perfectly fine:

**$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties**

```
TEST=Hello
```

**gradle.properties**

```
NAME = PJ
```

**build.gradle**

```
task hello << {
    println TEST
    println NAME
}
```

When `gradle hello` run I get the following output:

```
:hello
Hello
PJ

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.992 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested with intelliJ 13.1.4 built-in Gradle 1.7 and downloaded Gradle 2.0 and 2.1 version
Works fine. Make sure that path HOME/.gradle/ is set properly

gradle.properties:

```
TEST=Hello
NAME=PJ
```